# Rails - Stripe::InvalidRequestError in Bookings#new Must provide source or customer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments

I'm getting the above error in my Rails app. I have the following Stripe code in my Booking model -

**booking.rb**

```
    class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :event
    belongs_to :user

    validates :quantity, presence: true, numericality: { greater_than: 0 }
    validates :event, presence: true, numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 }

    before_save :set_price_to_zero_if_free

    def set_price_to_zero_if_free
       self.event.price >= 1    unless self.event.is_free
    end

    def reserve
        # Don't process this booking if it isn't valid
        #return unless valid?

        # We can always set this, even for free events because their price will be 0.
        #self.total_amount = booking.quantity * event.price

            # Free events don't need to do anything special
            if event.is_free?
            save!

            # Paid events should charge the customer's card
        else

            begin
                charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
                    amount: total_amount,
                    currency: "gbp",
                    source: 'token', 
                    description: "Booking created for amount #{total_amount}")
                    self.stripe_charge_id = charge.id
                    save!
            rescue Stripe::CardError => e
            errors.add(:base, e.message)
            false
            end
        end 
    end
end
```

**bookings_controller.rb**

```
  class BookingsController < ApplicationController

    before_action :authenticate_user!

    def new
        # booking form
        # I need to find the event that we're making a booking on
        @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
        # and because the event "has_many :bookings"
        @booking = @event.bookings.new(quantity: params[:quantity])
        # which person is booking the event?
        @booking.user = current_user
        #@booking.quantity = @booking.quantity
        #@total_amount = @booking.quantity.to_f * @event.price.to_f


    end

    def create

        # actually process the booking
        @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
        @booking = @event.bookings.new(booking_params)
        @booking.user = current_user

            if 
                @booking.reserve
                flash[:success] = "Your place on our event has been booked"
                redirect_to event_path(@event)
            else
                flash[:error] = "Booking unsuccessful"
                render "new"
            end
    end






    private

    def booking_params
        params.require(:booking).permit(:stripe_token, :quantity, :event_id, :stripe_charge_id)
    end



end
```

**booking.new.html.erb**

```
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" id="eventshow">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h2>Confirm Your Booking</h2>
        </div>
                  <div class="calculate-total">
                              <p>
                                  Confirm number of spaces you wish to book here:
                                    <input type="number" placeholder="1"  min="1" value="1" class="num-spaces">
                              </p>
                                <p>
                                    Total Amount
                                    £<span class="total" data-unit-cost="<%= @event.price %>">0</span>
                                </p>
                          </div>





                <%= simple_form_for [@event, @booking], id: "new_booking" do |form| %>



                 <span class="payment-errors"></span>

                <div class="form-row">
                    <label>
                      <span>Card Number</span>
                      <input type="text" size="20" data-stripe="number"/>
                    </label>
                </div>

                <div class="form-row">
                  <label>
                  <span>CVC</span>
                  <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="cvc"/>
                  </label>
                </div>

                <div class="form-row">
                    <label>
                        <span>Expiration (MM/YYYY)</span>
                        <input type="text" size="2" data-stripe="exp-month"/>
                    </label>
                    <span> / </span>
                    <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="exp-year"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">    

               <%= form.button :submit %>


            </div> 

<% end %>
<% end %>

      </div>
  </div>
</div>  

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.calculate-total input').on('keyup change', calculateBookingPrice);

function calculateBookingPrice() {
  var unitCost = parseFloat($('.calculate-total .total').data('unit-cost')),
      numSpaces = parseInt($('.calculate-total .num-spaces').val()),
      total = (numSpaces * unitCost).toFixed(2);

  if (isNaN(total)) {
    total = 0;
  }

  $('.calculate-total span.total').text(total);
}

  $(document).ready(calculateBookingPrice)

</script>



<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  Stripe.setPublishableKey('<%= STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY %>');
  var stripeResponseHandler = function(status, response) {
    var $form = $('#new_booking');

    if (response.error) {
    // Show the errors on the form
    $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
    $form.find('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
    // token contains id, last4, and card type
    var token = response.id;
    // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
    $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="booking[stripe_token]"     />').val(token));
    // and submit
    $form.get(0).submit();
    }
  };

  // jQuery(function($)  { - changed to the line below
  $(document).on("ready page:load", function () {

    $('#new_booking').submit(function(event) {
      var $form = $(this);

      // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
      $form.find('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true);

      Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);

      // Prevent the form from submitting with the default action
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

I don't understand why I'm getting the error when I'm clearly including source within my stripe code. I've expressed it above as self.stripe_token but I've tried just stripe_token but still get the same error. My understanding is I need to provide either source or customer, not both, and that it needs to be source rather than customer.

What am I missing?

Comment: i would try with hardcoded token in place of `self.stripe_token` to check if it's a wrong call to api issue or simple assignment issue e.g `self.stripe_token` is nil ?

Comment: How would you input that? I've tried a couple of different ways and nothing. I don't think I'd get this error if stripe_token was nil, would I?

Comment: add a debugging code `puts charge.inspect` before the `save!` and check your console to see what's wrong! you should also put more code in your question to explain where above snippet is called!

Comment: I've added controller and views. Let me know if you spot anything there.

Answer (score 0):

If you get "Must provide source or customer" as the error message, that means that `self.stripe_token` in your code must be either `nil` or an empty string.

You need to make sure that the `source` parameter's value is a valid token ID. The token should be created client-side, with [Checkout](http://zcheck) or [Stripe.js](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js). Once the token has been created, you need to send it to your server (typically as a POST parameter) so you can use it in your [charge creation request](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge).

You can also check your account's logs in your dashboard to see the requests that are sent by your integration, which is very helpful when debugging issues: https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs/overview.

Comment: Previously I had my stripe charge code in my bookings controller with card: @booking.stripe_token and it processed the payment albeit would only process one booking not multiple. It's only when I've moved it to my booking model that it's now not working. Why would this be?

Comment: Does it make any difference if I'm using an old API version? Do I need to refresh the token keys I've been using up to this point? As I said on previous comment I had no issues before I moved my code out of the controller and into the model as you see above.

Comment: I doubt the API version is a factor here -- the issue is in your code, `self.stripe_token` does not contain the value of the token ID. Unfortunately I don't have much experience with Rails so I'm not sure how exactly POST parameters are passed around, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

My wild guess that `stripe_token` isn't an attribute in the `booking` model. That's why when you try to retrieve it's value with `self.stripe_token` it will give you `nil`.

Try passing the token from controller params to model instance method:

#### controller:

```
if @booking.reserve(booking_params['stripe_token'])
  # everything is good
else
  # ops
end
```

#### model:

```
def reserve(stripe_token)
  if event.is_free?
    save!
  else
    begin
      charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
                   amount: total_amount,
                   currency: "gbp",
                   source: stripe_token,
                    ....
       )
       # rest of method
  end
```

#### Update:

currently your code has the part where `total_amount` is set commented out!

usually you will want to make something like:

```
total_amount = self.booking.event.price * 100 #not really sure how should calculate this? 
charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
            amount: total_amount,
            currency: "gbp",
            source: 'token', 
            description: "Booking created for amount #{total_amount}"
)
```

Comment: I've implemented the above.Now I'm getting 'missing required param :amount' , any ideas?

Comment: Hi, I've had another look at this and the issue here is that you can't use a Stripe Token more than once.